# Xcode Bot CI Service SVN issues

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode5, xcode-server

I am not able to integrate Xcode 5 Bots successfully. I am using `https://svn` source to access my repository. The Xcode service error log is not that helpful. Did the following so far.

1. Self signed flag is set to true in the plist.
2. In the KeyChain the self signed cert is both in 'System' and 'login'.
3. Tried both Xcode 5.0.2 and 5.1DP

Is there anything that I am missing? Can Xcode service access SVN through https?

Error log attached
http://pastebin.com/jSpzXxQh

Answer (score 0):

Xcode should be able to - generally - but I had problems with it as well. I found a solution with svn+ssh that worked for a while ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19650444/continuous-integration-with-xcode-bots/19957327#19957327)) - but then I misconfigured something and it all went away.

I'd suggest to setup a GIT repository clone on a Mac Server (free for devs) and, if needed, sync the GIT with SVN using [subgit](http://subgit.com). Setting it up did not take too long.